# Complex Number - root

Tags: complex-analysis, contest-math

> The complex numbers $z$ and $w$ satisfy $z^{13} = w$, $w^{11} = z$, and the imaginary part of $z$ is $\sin\left(\frac{m\pi}n\right)$ for relatively prime positive integers $m$ and $n$ with $m < n$. Find $n$.

**Answer: $n = 71$**

My attempt:

> We can assume if:
>   $$z = R(\cos(\frac{m\pi}{n}) + i\sin(\frac{m\pi}{n})$$ Then,
>   $R = 1$ since $\Im\{z\} = \sin(\frac{m\pi}{n}) \implies z = e^{i\frac{m\pi}{n}}$
>   Hence, by De-Movire,
>   $$z^{142} = e^{i\frac{142m\pi}{n}} = 1$$
>   $$z^{142} = \cos(\frac{142m\pi}{n}) + i\sin(\frac{142m\pi}{n}) = 1$$
>   So, $\sin(\frac{142m\pi}{n}) = 0$ is to be satisfied right?
>   $$\frac{142 m \pi}{n} = \pi \implies 142m = n$$
>   $n = 71$ though means that the fraction is not relatively prime?

Comment: How is $z^{142}=1$ ? It can be $(zw)^{142}=1$ though. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: $z^{143} = (z^{13})^{11} = w^{11} = z$.

Comment: @UmbertoP., Ah right! That was a stupid question to ask. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot conclude from $$\sin(\frac{142m\pi}{n}) = 0$$ that $\frac{142m\pi}{n} = \pi$. In fact, this would give $$z^{142} = -1$$ (since $\cos\pi=-1$), which is clearly not what you want.

Letting $\theta = \frac{142m\pi}{n}$ for brevity, the condition $z^{142}=1$ is equivalent to $\cos\theta = 1$ and $\sin\theta = 0$. So in fact $\theta = 2k\pi$ in necessary and sufficient ($k \in \mathbb Z$). From here I'll let you work out that $n=71$ must hold, though you cannot deduce $m$.